# How to redefine Scheme/Racket fundamental forms?

Tags: forms, scheme, lisp, racket, redefine

Racket has built-in fundamental form 2-arm `if`, but it doesn't have the word `else`, so I want to add the `else` word to it.

This code works:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-rule (myif Cond Form1 else Form2)
  (if Cond Form1 Form2)
)

(myif #t (displayln 1) else (displayln 2))
```

However `myif` is undesired as keyword, changing it to `if` raises error:

```
if: use does not match pattern: (if Cond Form1 else Form2)
in: (if #t (displayln 1) (displayln 2))
```

How to redefine the form `if`?

Comment: When you redefine `if`, make sure you change uses of the "old" `if` so that they don't accidentally point to the wrong one. In the new definition you want to delegate to the old `if`, so I recommend importing the old if with `(require (only-in racket/base [if old-if]))`, then using `old-if` where you intend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above is "correct" at some level, but there are some mistakes.

1. `define-syntax-rule` is not from `syntax/parse/define`. If you want to use `define-syntax-rule`, there's no need to `(require syntax/parse/define)`.
2. What will happen when I call `(if #t 1 2 3)` with your `if`? `else` in your macro is a pattern variable, so it can match against anything. Do you intend to allow this to happen? If not, this is where you can use the features of `syntax/parse/define`. You can write:

   ```
   (require syntax/parse/define)
   (define-simple-macro (if test-expr:expr 
                            {~datum then} 
                            then-expr:expr 
                            {~datum else} 
                            else-expr:expr)
     (racket:if test-expr then-expr else-expr))
   ```

   So `(if 1 then 2 else 3)` will expand to `(racket:if 1 2 3)`, but `(if 1 0 2 0 3)` will fail with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @AlexKnauth for the comment, I can redefine `if` as below:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(require (only-in racket/base [if r-if]))

(define-syntax-rule (if Cond Form1 else Form2)
  (r-if Cond Form1 Form2)
)

(if #t (displayln 1) else (displayln 2))
```